# CS0433 error; Oracle error

Tags: c#, oracle11g, odp.net

When I try to run a web application that uses Oracle 11g database, I get:

```
CS0433: The type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader' 
exists in both 
'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\2.121.1.0__89b483f429c47342\oracle.dataaccess.dll' 
and 
'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.121.1.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll'
```

I tried different ways of adding references to Oracle.DataAccess.DLL and Oracle.Web.DLL, using the DLLs in GAC, copying the DLLs to bin folder (from `C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\ASP.NET\bin\2.x`) and referencing it there, but can't shake this error off.

It happens in:

```
Line 136:        private List<TrackerObject> MapDbData(OracleDataReader dr)
Line 137:        {
```

web.config contains:

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Oracle.DataAccess, 
         Version=2.112.3.0, 
         Culture=neutral, 
         PublicKeyToken=89B483F429C47342"/>
```

I also tried to uninstall the policy, as was suggested in some sites, but to no avail:

```
gacutil /u Policy.2.102.Oracle.DataAccess
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Oracle Installer to install "Oracle Providers for ASP.NET and Oracle Data Provider for .NET"? Trying to do it yourself manually is fraught with errors, as you are finding out. Also, you don't need to use the 11.2 version of ODP.NET just because your database is 11.2. If this is a new application I would recommend using 12.1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the .Net versions 2.0 and 4.0 of the Oracle data provider are both being added into your project for some reason. Determine why differing versions are occurring, fix and build with one target version.

Comment: I changed the target framework to 4.0; removed existing references to oracle.dataaccess and oracle.web (version 2.112.3.0) and added references to version 4.112.3.0 (using VS, under Assemblies\Extensions). Now the referenced DLLs are: Version 4.112.3.0, runtime version: v4.0.30319, path: C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_2\ODP.NET\bin\4\oracledataaccess.dll. However, now I am getting: "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client "